# WebAPI DLL in IIS isn't loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dll, asp.net-web-api

We have one SPA using WebAPI as a backend hosted at one domain. We are sharing some authentication code between this main site and our secondary site by pulling it out into a class library in the first site's VS solution and compiling it from there. I then take the DLL from the first site and add copy/paste it over to the lib folder I have for the second VS solution.

I add a reference to it in the second VS solution and it runs fine locally. However, when we build this solution in TFS and it winds up on our server's IIS folders I get an internal server error whenever I try to use calls from this DLL.

Is there a step I'm missing once it's up on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.

I need to add the DLL to VS2012 to ensure that I could add it to TFS source control. Then I needed to change the properties on the DLL to have no Build Action and change Copy to Output directory to "Copy".

I suppose IIS was interpreting the previous settings as "Don't look in /bin" which meant it couldn't find it.